# Javascript linked externally not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zpfWJCdNAI) two part tutorial on how to write a really efficient parallax effect with JavaScript and jQuery

It works flawlessly when I put the JS directly into the html file, but when I link it externally, it doesn't work. Why??

[**Working version (internal JS)**](https://7568fa8ec856c21498701e0edd220440c5c75264.googledrive.com/host/0B4rWYiw5-JZtfm1wNE1iMkY1b0tuaXFnaUZmaWFsSU5XLXQtaTh5U2ozVFB0NHgyVXpOOW8/test.html)

**Non-working version:**

```js
(function ($) {

    var $container = $(".parallax");
    var $divs = $container.find("div.parallax-background");
    var thingBeingScroll = document.body;
    var liHeight = $divs.eq(0).closest("li").height();
    var diffHeight = $divs.eq(0).height() - liHeight;
    var len = $divs.length;

    var i, div, li, offset, scroll, top, transform;

    var offsets = $divs.get().map(function (div, d) {
        return $(div).offset();
    });

    var render = function () {

         top = thingBeingScroll.scrollTop;

         for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             div = $divs[i];

             offset = top - offsets[i].top;

             scroll = ~~((offset / liHeight * diffHeight) * 2);

             transform = 'translate3d(0px,' + scroll + 'px,0px)';

             div.style.webkitTransform = transform;
             div.style.MozTransform = transform;
             div.style.msTransform = transform;
             div.style.OTransform = transform;
             div.style.transform = transform;
         }
     };

     (function loop() {
         requestAnimationFrame(loop);
         render();
     })();

     (function () {
         var lastTime = 0;
         var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
         for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
             window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
             window.cancelAnimationFrame =
               window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
         }

         if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
             window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
                 var currTime = new Date().getTime();
                 var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
                 var id = window.setTimeout(function () { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
                   timeToCall);
                 lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
                 return id;
             };

         if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
             window.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
                 clearTimeout(id);
             };
     }());

 })(jQuery);
```

```css
body, ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  body {
   height: 2500px;
  }

  ul li {
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 600px;
  }

  .parallax-background {
   height: 700px;
   background-size: cover; 
  }

  .lens {
   background-image: url('http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/sigma-art-lenses.jpg');
  }
  .beach {
   background-image: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2422/3799310645_92dba468ae_b.jpg');
  }
  .wolf {
   background-image: url('http://images.alphacoders.com/102/102853.jpg');
  }
  .flower {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Aoo6BAk.jpg');
  }
```

```html
  <ul class="parallax">
   <li>
    <div class="parallax-background flower"></div>
   </li>
  </ul>

  <h1>Content</h1>
```

Comment: what errors are thrown? Check broswer console to make sure file is loading...and loading ***after*** jQuery library

Comment: Check your console man!

Comment: Nothing happening in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the paths to your `parallax.js` script and `parallax.css` are invalid:

```
<script src="parallax.js" type="parallax.js"></script> <!--Parallax JS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="parallax.css"> <!--Parallax CSS-->
```

Going to those URLs (by clicking the linked files in Chrome) send me to Google's login page. Try changing your script src and link href to use absolute paths and ensure that both are visible to the public.

Comment: My god, I hate it when I make stupid mistakes like that, then spend all day trying to find what I did wrong. Thanks!